# How to set all values that aren't a certain set of values to be 'Other' in SQL

Tags: mysql

So i have data like this:

```
ID    BOO
001   erns
002   delta
003   hanny
004   milk
005   milk
```

And basically I wanna say, If it doesn't equal milk or delta, it's "other". But in the real situation, it's 12 or so cases where I dont want other. So is there a way to do this in MySQL where i can say

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN BOO <> IN ("hanny","milk") THEN "OTHER"
          END BOO2
```

Expected Output:

```
ID    BOO2
001   other
002   other
003   hanny
004   milk
005   milk
```

Comment: Is this question about MySQL or Snowflake? Please tag only one. And not `r`, probably.

Comment: If you want a (sorry, 'wanna') two-column output, you cannot have a 3-column input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT ID, 
CASE
    WHEN BOO NOT IN ('hanny','milk') THEN 'OTHER'
    ELSE BOO
END BOO2
FROM YOURTABLE
```

Note that in `SQL` syntax you should use `''` for strings, and not `""`. This is different than what `R` allows.